# Actionscript 3: Convert raw PNG data to DisplayObject

Tags: actionscript-3, image, actionscript

I'm trying to convert the raw PNG data from a file I've loaded via URLLoader into a usable DisplayObject. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data is in a ByteArray, you can load it into a Loader:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.loadBytes(pngData);
addChild(loader);
```

Comment: It's not as semantic as I'd like it to be, but it works. Thank-you!